# Portable method to extract uint8_t bytes from uint32_t values in c

Tags: c, casting

I am taking a uint32_t value and extracting it into four uint8_t values.  My code works with gcc 4.9, but I don't know how portable it is.

This works:

```
uint32_t u32 = 0xdeadbeef;

uint8_t byte3 = (uint8_t)(u32 >> 24);  // 0xde
uint8_t byte2 = (uint8_t)(u32 >> 16);  // 0xad
uint8_t byte1 = (uint8_t)(u32 >> 8);   // 0xbe
uint8_t byte0 = (uint8_t)u32;          // 0xef
```

Is this standards-compliant? Or should I be more explicit like so:

```
uint32_t u32 = 0xdeadbeef;

uint8_t byte3 = (uint8_t)((u32 & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
uint8_t byte2 = (uint8_t)((u32 & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
uint8_t byte1 = (uint8_t)((u32 & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
uint8_t byte0 = (uint8_t)(u32 & 0x000000FF);
```

I'm using the casts to quiet the conversion warnings I receive when compiling with the -Wconversion switch.

Comment: You just shouldn't need casts in either case. The implicit conversion to the bytes should do the right thing. Unsigned arithmetic is defined like that.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt The explicit cast quiets the explicit warning (e.g -Wconversion).

Comment: @chux, that's just the wrong approach. Casts are evil, conversions are good. Cast quieten *any* wrong doing, implicit conversions are made to to the right thing.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt The [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508747/safe-way-to-extract-uint8-t-bytes-from-uint32-t-values-in-c?noredirect=1#comment52878690_32508747) mentions a reason for the `(uint8_t)`.  It neither endorses nor commends casting.  Implicit conversions have their dark-size too.  In this simplistic case, there is little benefit for the cast other than to quiet the warning flagged by "-Wconversion".  Some coding standards (unfortunately) oblige use of "-Wconversion" should we agree with them or not.

Comment: Thank you @JensGustedt.  I am only casting to quiet the compiler warnings as chux suggested.  Could you tell me why casts are evil? I thought that the compiler would do the same thing whether it was performing an implicit conversion or an explicit cast.

Comment: @bitsmack, the main reason casts are evil is that they "work" (or pretend to) whatever you feed them. Basically you tell the compiler that you know what you are doing and that he has to shut up. What you really want in the cases of your example is a mask, and you are somehow abusing casts for doing that. Another reason that C casts are evil is their syntax. It is really hard to come up with a regexp that would find all the casts in a code, e.g. Good C code gets all its types correct and has no cast at all, and no warnings either.

Comment: @JensGustedt Got it, thanks. My company's default compiler setup uses `-Wconversion` which spawns a warning for every implicit conversion.  So I either use casts or I get a bunch of warnings :)  Are there any protections that I would lose if I turned off `-Wconversion`?

Comment: @bitsmack, not that come to mind, immediately. The problem is probably that your code already contains a lot of casts. So if you turn it off *and* remove all the casts, you might get a lot of warnings about `unsigned` to `signed` conversion. There you would have a chance to get all the types right :) Then you will perhaps see the compiler complaining about attempted conversions between incompatible pointers. There you'd have discovered real bugs. For more about that you could see https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/dont-use-casts-i/

Comment: @JensGustedt This is very helpful, thanks! I was wondering why I wasn't getting type warnings :) It looks like I need to set aside a day and remove the casts.  I just asked a question about this topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32527685/3380131), mostly so you would have a place to post these comments as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both work and are compliant.

The mask-less  `uint8_t byte0 = (uint8_t)u32;` is cleaner.

Portability limited to systems that support `uint32_t` and `uint8_t`.  (Certainly most do)

Answer (score 3):

Your first option is totally fine!
There is no need to clear the unneeded bits.

The lower unneeded bits will be removed by the shift right `>>` operation and the upper unneeded bits will be removed by the casting `(uint8_t)`.